# Windows 10 Task Manager not showing WINWORD.exe process

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-word

In `Windows 10`, I have a Microsoft WORD application opened but the `Task Manager` is not showing the `WINWORD.exe` process there as demonstrated below. Why it may be happening?:

**Task Manager - screenshot of Apps** [showing MS WORD app]:

[image]

**Task Manager - screenshot of Processes** [NOTE showing WINWORD.exe process. Processes names are sorted in alphabetical order]:

[image]

Comment: What is not showing? It appears to be fine (Word is the application after all). My Task Manger shows Word the same way.

Comment: @John If I remember correctly, if the WORD is opened, in the old window systems (Windows xp etc.) the process `WINWORD.exe` used to show in the Task Manager process column way down. In `Windows 10` task manager has two groups `Apps` and `Background Processes`. I thought `WINWORD.exe` would show under the group `Background Processes`. I may be missing something here. Could you please explain what's going on here?

Comment: just go to the details tab and all processes should be there

Comment: XP is nearly 20 years old and things have changed. What you see is normal. I see the same thing on my Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an expected behavior.

Word is now categorized as displayed in the “APPs”.

It doesn't appear in the background process.

It's not just word, I've found that all office software has this situation:

[image]

I tested word 2013 and office 365 word in the win10 environment, and neither of them appeared in the background process.

I infer that this is a change brought about by win10.

Comment: The problem is that the WinWord process does not even show in the Details tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, where I had multiple copies of MS Word running, and they did not show up in the Task Manager, either in Details or Processes.  They did show up in SysInternals Process Explorer.

Turns out that after I stopped Task Manager and opened it again, the WinWord.exe processes did show up!

So it appears that the Windows 10 Task Manager can get out of sync with what is happening on its computer and needs to be restarted to correctly list all processes.

Comment: I have seen the same issue of TM not updating the list correctly, but you dont't need to close/open. You can click one of the other taps like "performance", and then click back to "processes" this will make the list update properly (at least this time, you may need to repeat later)